# Would like to insert a dash into a column of data

Tags: sql, db2

I'm pulling a query that is giving me results that look like this "05629003".  I need my query to return the results like this "056290-03".  I figure I can get this done with a combination of SUBSTR and CONCAT functions, but was curious to see if there was an easier way to insert a dash to a specific spot.  The results will always be 8 digits long and I will always need the dash before the last two digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the [`INSERT` scalar function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000813.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F5-5-3-2-67) (not to be confused with the INSERT statement)

Here's an example that produces the value you are looking for:

```
select INSERT('05629003', 7,0,'-')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

I tested, and it worked on both Linux/Unix/Windows 9.7, and z/OS 10.

Comment: That is it!  Seems to be the DB2 equivalent of the "STUFF" function someone else proposed earlier.  This is much easier than the SUBSTR and CONCAT pairing I used as a work around.  Thank you, Sir!

Comment: Nice, I have not seen that before (working with db2 LUW since 1997 :-)